# Java Swing, how to change the layout after a Next button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have designed a GUI using Swing components. I have added a Next Button and when someone press it I want to appear another layout of the same GUI. Something like when I pressed proceed in this site in order to write the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you will want to use a `CardLayout`. You can define multiple panels to occupy the same space in the frame. You can swap the panel that is displayed based on your requirements.

So based on your question, the "Next" button would just display the next panel added to the `CardLayout`.

Read the section from the swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.